# Magento2x equivalent class for Mage_Core?

Tags: magento2

What is the equivalent Magento2 class for the below

1)  `Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action`

2) `Mage_Core_Block_Template`

Basically for **Core** ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In **Magento 1** it was

```
Mage_Core_Block_Template
```

And in **Magento2**

```
\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
```

In **Magento 1** it was

```
Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
```

And in **Magento2** frontend

```
\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
```

And in **Magento2** Admin

```
\Magento\Backend\App\Action
```

Answer (score 3):

For Magento 2 Frontend extend your controller with `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action` and for admin extend your class with `\Magento\Backend\App\Action`

For Block, extend your block class with `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`

Hopefully this satisfy your question